# Find $\frac{dI}{da}$ and $\frac{dI}{db}$ for the integral $I=\int_a^{b} {1\over log(x)} dx$

Tags: integration, analysis

I've tried using the fundamental theorem of calculus, but it just doesn't seem correct. Any help would be appreciated as I don't know how to approach this.

Answer (score 4):

The fundamental theorem of calculus states that if $a > 0$ and $$I(t) = \int_a^t \frac{1}{\log x} \, dx, \quad t > 0$$ then $I'(t) = \dfrac{1}{\log t}$ for all $t > 0$. You can apply this directly.

It will be useful to remember that $\displaystyle \int_t^b \frac{1}{\log x} \, dx = - \int_b^t \frac{1}{\log x} \, dx.$